# Runtime error "SYSTEM_ABAP_ACCESS_DENIED" when using SUBMIT via custom report

Tags: abap

I am trying to use cl_salv_bs_runtime_info in order to get the ALV data in memory after using SUBMIT in a standard report.

The code for the above is:

```
REPORT ztest1.

FIELD-SYMBOLS <lt_pay_data>   TYPE ANY TABLE.
DATA lr_pay_data              TYPE REF TO data.

cl_salv_bs_runtime_info=>set(
   EXPORTING display  = abap_false
             metadata = abap_false
             data     = abap_true ).

SUBMIT rfts7000
 AND RETURN.

TRY.
    cl_salv_bs_runtime_info=>get_data_ref(
      IMPORTING r_data = lr_pay_data ).
    ASSIGN lr_pay_data->* TO <lt_pay_data>.
  CATCH cx_salv_bs_sc_runtime_info.
    MESSAGE `Unable to retrieve ALV data` TYPE 'E'.
ENDTRY.

cl_salv_bs_runtime_info=>clear_all( ).
```

When it is run the program rfts7000 runs and prompts for data selection.

After submitting the selection screen i get:

[image: Error]

ST22 extract:
[image: ST22 text]
Any ideas?

Comment: This question has some interesting comments in [SCN](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12838384/runtime-error-system-abap-access-denied-when-using.html) forum.

Comment: Indeed it has. I will answer the question based on my findings there.

Comment: Wow-wow, what an interesting error. Never knew that HANA is maintaining blacklists :)

Comment: @Suncatcher I believe the blacklist source is the ERP itself as SAP is struggling to move to a new ERA after 40 years and they are trying to make people drop old habits and processes.

Answer (score 5):

After some research based on comments in the relative [SCN Question](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12838384/runtime-error-system-abap-access-denied-when-using.html) the case is as follows.

The system is throwing this error in order to prevent me from running outdated and obsolete (or soon to be obsolete) programs.

The specific program that i call through `SUBMIT`, is part of the Cash Management (CM) module which although is still active in S4/HANA , i think that is going to be replaced.

So **SAP Note 2392358** says exactly that: *"According to the S/4HANA Simplification List, the totals tables of classic CM are completed eliminated and therefore they shall not be accessed any more."*

In order for this protection to work, SAP has a blacklist where the programs are listed in order not to be used.

But there is a possible "backdoor" to that as explained in **SAP Note 2249880**. The backdoor is just a way to remove a program from the Blacklist.

The note suggests to get approval from SAP first and then to follow the steps to remove the program from the blacklist.

As a side note, i worry more that we have implemented cash management in an outdated module rather than worrying about the error after all...